What do we mean by ‘Selected at random’ and “randomly selected “
I have a doubt in a probability question which is basic high school level but there is a thin line of distinction in the language of the question and what is supposed to be asked
If a and b are randomly chosen from the set {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} then the probability that the expression ax^2+bx+1 > 0 for all x belongs to R is p/q where p and q are prime
My only doubt is that are we selecting numbers a and b simultaneously from the bucket and they are ought to be distinct or are we selecting randomly but not simultaneously (implying a and b can have same values)
What does selecting at random mean actually?
How do we decode the word random in this question  ?

Indeed, it's ambiguous. I would say the second one... but it's just my interpretation...

I’m sorry, but there’s not enough info here for us to tell. It’s ambiguous. You’ll need to ask whomever gave you the problem.

In general what do we mean by ‘selected at random’..

There is no mathematical committee that certifies what "selected at random" exactly has to mean. Only  they know if they mean drawing with/without replacement. Let's put this aside. There are not that many choices to select $a,b$ from that set at random. What on earth does the rest of that homework question mean? What is R for example?

R is Real numbers
